# Subfolders in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, admin

I'm new to CodeIgniter, and I need some help. I'd like to implement the following:

- View a user's profile via:
  http://localhost/profile/johndoe
- Administrate a user's profile via:
  http://localhost/admin/profile/johndoe
- Be able to accomplish even further processing via:
  http://localhost/admin/profile/create
  ...and...
  http://localhost/admin/profile/edit/johndoe

I've already created the admin object and secured it. Do I have to create a profile function under admin, and work with the URI to process accordingly? Is there a better way?

Comment: the ci tag is for continuous integration, not for codeigniter :)

Comment: What do you mean "I've already created the admin object and secured it"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not such a good idea.

If you want to implement those URLs, you need two controllers:

1. Profile, with the function `index`
2. Admin, with the function `profile`

In Admin, the `profile` function has to read the first argument (create/edit/[userid]) and then do something accordingly. (You also must make sure that no user can call himself "create" or "edit".)

I would instead use only one controller with the functions `show`, `edit`, and `create` (or `add`). Much easier. Then you would get these URLs:

- http://localhost/profile/show/johndoe
- http://localhost/profile/edit/johndoe
- http://localhost/profile/create/johndoe

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution I was looking for:
http://www.clipmarks.com/clipmark/75D02C9E-3E76-483E-8CCE-30403D891969/

Thanks, Christian D, I like your solution better than mine. I'm going with it.